# python pandas reading space separated data

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, text

I have text file with 6 space separated fields as below :

```
702377236289228800 2016-02-24 09:19:17 +03 <Aadil_Siddiqui> #HECRanking Rs71 Bil bdget alloctd 2 HEC is not in gud hands. v can imagne dat on which criteria #HEC is sending studnts abroad on Scholrshp
```

I want to read the 6 fields into a pandas DF, but setting the delimiter to space is giving me the following error.

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 31 fields in line 10, saw 35

Here is the code :

```
data = pd.read_csv("twitter_file_path.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["seq", "date", "Hour", "GMT","userID","text"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all data in one column with some separator not exist in text like `|` and then for new columns use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n` parameter and no separator, because space is default sep:

```
data = pd.read_csv("twitter_file_path.txt", sep="|", names=['data'])
print (data)
                                                data
0  702377236289228800 2016-02-24 09:19:17 +03 <Aa...

data = data['data'].str.split(n=5, expand=True)
data.columns = ["seq", "date", "Hour", "GMT","userID","text"]
print (data)
                  seq        date      Hour  GMT            userID  \
0  702377236289228800  2016-02-24  09:19:17  +03  <Aadil_Siddiqui>   

                                                text  
0  #HECRanking Rs71 Bil bdget alloctd 2 HEC is no...
```

Comment: but character | can exist in some lines

Comment: Haha, I really can't know, cause I have 32k profile files from different languages, so I guess any char can occur